# A way to check the accuracy of a Markov chain?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, mathematical-modeling

I am not sure whether I should post this question on MSE or SSE. I will post it here 1st to see if I can get some feedback.

Say I have a finite discrete Markov chain constructed maybe using some data set. Is there any good way of checking it's accuracy? Any model will be required to be tested or maybe back tested in order to validate it. So I need to know if there are any such methods for Markov Chains. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have enough data, then you can collect transition pairs (i to j) and do a [chi-square test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test). If $N_i$ is the number of transition pairs starting at $i$, the each transition pair (i to j) should occur $N_ip_{ij}$  times. These are your cell expected values in the chi-square test. Note, you will need enough data so that $N_ip_{ij}>5\;\; \forall ij$

If $T$ is the number of transition probabilities, and $S$ the number of states, then your test will have $T-S$ degrees of freedom.

**Example for OP**

Lets say we have a simple $2 \times 2$ transition matrix $M$ for a two-sate Markov chain.

At each step, you observe the actual state, $S_t\in\{0,1\}$. Lets say that we observe the system for $T$ time steps. What we want to know is if $M$ is a plausible explanation for the dynamics of $S$.

To do this, we note that the transition matrix is really just a bunch of conditional probabilities:

$p_{i,j}=P(S_{t+1}=j|S_t=i)$ Therefore, the row-sums of $M$ will equal 1. This provides the basis for our chi-squared frequency table:

1. First, count the number of times $S_t=1$ for $t<T$, call this $N_1$
2. Second,count the number of times $S_t=2$ for $t<T$, call this $N_2$
3. Note that $T=N_1+N_2 +1$, so we have accounted for all the states except the last one, $S_T$
4. Now, for the states that are in state $i$ count the number of times the next state was $j$, call this $N_{ij}$
5. Form a $2 \times 2$ matrix $O$, where row 1 is the State 1 transitions, and row 2 is the State 2 transition.
6. Let $O_{ij}=N_{ij}$ These are the observed frequencies of each of the four possible transitions.
7. For the chi-square test, we also need an expected frequency. Create another $2 \times 2$ matrix $E$, where row 1 is the State 1 transitions, and row 2 is the State 2 transition.
8. Let $E_{ij}=p_{ij}N_i$ You'll need enough data to ensure $E_{ij}>5\;\; \forall ij$
9. You now have the observed and expected cell counts you need for the chi-square test. Just select your Type I error rate and you're set.

Comment: This is new. Thanks alot. I still cannot figure out how exactly to apply this to a Markov chain but now I have something to work on. So what you are basically saying is if we predict some values for say 1 week ahead using a MC and then we wait to see what will actually happens and then carry out a chi square test to validate the model?

Comment: @Heisenberg I went through a simple example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer this is brilliant. But I have a small confusion. I approximated a Markov Chain for a small research of mine using some observed data. Since the chain is derived from observations with what should I compare this to do the Chi Square test? By obtaining more observations?

Comment: @Heisenberg Ah, so you fitted a Markov model. In that case, you either try to test your fitted model against the data used to fit it (at a penalty of $(\#S-1)$ degrees of freedom!). Or (much more preferable) just gather more data and test your fitted model against that.

Comment: Even I would prefer the latter. Thanks I learned alot

Comment: To fit the same data set what is the degree of freedom ? T-S+1?

Comment: @Heisenberg Well, each row must sum to $N_i$ so you have $\#S$ of those, plus you need to estimate $\#S-1$ probabilities in each row, so you have another set of $\#S$ constraints so you would have $\#S^2-2\#S$ degrees of freedom compared to  $\#S^2-\#S$ for applying to a new data set.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry for the late reply. I would much appreciate if you could suggest some text or research paper where I can do some further reading on this :) I hope to add this to my undergraduate thesis. Thanks again for helping me out

Comment: @Heisenberg any text on categorical data analysis or the chi-square test should be fine. I used a very basic chi-square test, which is covered in most intro stats texts.

Comment: I found notes on the chi squared test but could not find any formal notes on the use of it in the field of Markov chains

Comment: @Heisenberg sounds like you've got yourself an interesting thesis then ;-)